# Why angular-cli generates index.html instead of javascript for some bundle files - main and inline?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When running **`ng build --prod -aot`** I found out via Chrome Console that the angular-cli in a way is generating `HTML` instead of javascript for the following 2 files:  **`inline.ef2cca55df62b04c3a6e.bundle.js`** and : **`main.f6759214c702206e325d.bundle.js`** which causes this error: **`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.ad37cd45a71cb38eee76.bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined at polyfills.ad37cd45a71cb38eee76.bundle.js:1`** when trying to call the app on the browser.

The error makes sense as HTML beginns with: `<!docytpe html>`.

Also when I check with Chrome/Network I see **`Content-Type:text/html`**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9898/main.f6759214c702206e325d.bundle.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:9898
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:598
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Mon, 04 Dec 2017 12:45:38 GMT
ETag:"5a2541be-256"
Last-Modified:Mon, 04 Dec 2017 12:38:22 GMT
Server:nginx/1.13.7
```

One important thing to mention is that the app contains 2 sub folders under `/dist` for the translation: `/en` and `/es` where I did generate same needed files/bundles.

So I do have at the end:

```
/dist
   /en
      styles.xxxxxxxxxxx.css
      inline.xxxxxxxxxxx.js
      main.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.js
      polyfills.xxxxxxxx.js
   /es
      styles.xxxxxxxxxxx.css
      inline.xxxxxxxxxxx.js
      main.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.js
      polyfills.xxxxxxxx.js

   styles.xxxxxxxxxxx.css
   inline.xxxxxxxxxxx.js
   main.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.js
   polyfills.xxxxxxxx.js`
```

When I call the app first under e.g: `http:localhost:9090/`, it loads the files and the correct content and router which is: `http:localhost:9090/home`, but when I try to serve to the different languages e.g. `http:localhost:9090/en` oder `http:localhost:9090/es`, then it doesn't work and throws: `Unexpected token <, and I can see that`main.xxxxx.js`and`inline.xxxxxxx.js` contain really a HTML Markup, not JavaScript.

Comment: the cli is not generating html files for the bundle.js files. They are js files. Your server is serving index.html when a client requests those bundle.js resources. So this is a server configuration issue.

Comment: @LLai: I'am talking about the index.html which is in the root of the `/dist` folder. The index.html which binds/contains and has a reference to JS files.  Anyway, I understand what you want to say. I was a kind of thinking about a server config issue, but to be honest, I was not 100% sure. So this might be a docker config task.

Comment: But in the other hand, isn't it correct that way? Server serves `index.html` which from it sides requests bundles (JavaScript files). These are available in the same folder where `index.html` is being saved/generated.

Comment: Correct, but depending on how your server is configured, it might be returning `index.html` when `index.html` is requesting the `bundle.js` files. On your client, when you view the `x.x.bundle.js` file network request, what does the response look like? Is it your `index.html` file?

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and i think it is related to routing.
cause the same page is working fine on an iis when i do rewrite url.
on apache it is failing. 
so my assumption is that my apache routing is wrong, as i am no apache expert
hope the hint helps